# typeError: Failed to execute 'observe' on 'ResizeObserver': parameter 1 is not of type 'Element'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

To explain the context, I am building a instagram carousal for a gatsby project. The images within the carousel are displayed by

```
                  {data.allInstaNode.edges.map((image) => (
                        <Background
                            src={image.node.localFile.childImageSharp.fluid}
                            className="img-fluid"
                            height="38vh"
                            width="100%"
                        />
                    ))}
```

The Background component that is rendering the images uses Gatsby background image and is as follows

```
import React from 'react';
import BackgroundImage from 'gatsby-background-image';

export default function Background(props) {
    return (
        <BackgroundImage
            xs={props.xs}
            sm={props.sm}
            md={props.md}
            lg={props.lg}
            fluid={props.src}
            style={{ height: `${props.height}`, width: `${props.width}`, margin: '1rem' }}
        >
            {props.children}
        </BackgroundImage>
    );
}
```

This problem is that this content used to render just fine, and does not do so now as it is is giving me this error - TypeError: Failed to execute 'observe' on 'ResizeObserver': parameter 1 is not of type 'Element'.

I did some searching to solve this issue and came across this solution which seems to be promising but is not very clear to me- https://github.com/souporserious/react-measure/issues/76

can anyone help?:)

Comment: Did you figure this out? I just came across this on a typeahead component.

Comment: was seeing the same problem, was occurring because the dom element was not on the page yet at the time it was trying to be referenced

Answer (score 6):

This is occurring because the **element does not exist yet** at the time you are attempting to reference it.

You can use `setTimeout(() => { yourCode },100)` so it will wait 100ms before attempting to access the dom element, or you can use

```
await waitUntil(() => myDomElement != null, { timeout: 20000 });
.... <your code>
```

This will wait for your element to be not null before running your code (above code will wait up to 20s, timeout is in ms)

Comment: I agree with the idea but not the execution. For those having the same issue and you want to check whether an element is rendered, use the mutationObserver method. Its great and much cleaner than a timeout

Comment: @Kisho I'm assuming mutationObserver will not overcomplicate things / is easier to read than adding a 1 line timeout?

Answer (score 0):

This is because the observer didn't receive the values of the variables.

```
{data.allInstaNode.edges.map((image) => (
                        <Background
                            src= 
                       {image.node.localFile.childImageSharp.fluid}
                            className="img-fluid"
                            height="38vh"
                         screenSize={'sm'|| 'xs'||'lg' || 'md'}
                            width="100%"
                        />
                    ))}


import React from 'react';
import BackgroundImage from 'gatsby-background-image';

export default function Background(props) {

const [screenSizes,setScreenSize] = React.useState('')
const [imgSrc,setImageSrc] = React.useState('')


React.useEffect(()=>{
   setScreenSize(props.screenSize);
 },[props.screenSize])

React.useEffect(()=>{
   setImageSrc(props.src);
 },[props.src])

return (
        <BackgroundImage
            xs={screenSizes==='xs'}
            sm={screenSizes==='sm'}
            md={screenSizes==='md'}
            lg={screenSizes==='lg'}
            fluid={props.imgSrc}
            style={{ height: `${props.height || 'auto'}`, width: 
           `${props.width || 'auto'}`, margin: '1rem' }}
        >
            {props.children}
        </BackgroundImage>
    );
}
```